# 'agree' as a transitive verb

Tags: difference, british-english

> [[OED:]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4146?rskey=4w819R&result=2&isAdvanced=false) 15. {trans.} = To arrange or settle (something requiring the consent of several parties); to come to an agreement on.
>
> In modern use `chiefly Brit.` Apparently RARE in the 19th cent.

I already understand, and so ask NOT about, the above definition. Instead, why's this `chiefly British` use transitive, whereas North American use of this definition, requires a preposition such as [these](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/73696/50720). What does the preposition truly mean, if British English can omit it?

Footnote: I encountered this on p 187, *Urban Geography*, 3 ed., by Michael Pacione:

> At the local government level,
> Agenda 21 of the 1991 Rio Earth Summit **agreed a
> number** of proposals relating to waste management,
> energy conservation, the integration of land-use and
> transport planning, and the protection of natural habitats.

Answer (score 4):

In AmE, we don't use "these", we use **on** . And we don't use "agree" as a transitive verb.. We use it as an **intransitive** verb.

The preposition is not needed in BrE because the transitive verb does take a direct object. (V+DO)

- British: We agreed a time for the meeting.
  We agreed the terms of the contract.
- American: We agreed **on** a time for the meeting. We agreed **on** the terms of the contract. Later, he agreed *to* (accepted) the terms of the contract.

The AmE version does not use a direct object.  The prepositional phrases "on a time" , "on the terms" are adverbial. 
"We agreed." 
"We agreed on xxx."
"We agreed that xxx."  (xxx is true)
"We agreed to [do xxx]."
"We agreed in principle."

Comment: It is also often used in AmE with the preposition "to": _Agreed **to** the deal_